# How to solve this kind of div position related issue

Tags: html, css

Need help to display the inner most div over the parent without scroll.
I don't want any scroll on parent div when child div display:block.
and I cant remove .divrelative{position:relative;},
and i have fixed hight of parent.

```css
.parent{background:#ccc; padding:10px; height:100px; overflow-y:auto;}

.divrelative{position:relative;}

.child{ background:#fff; width:80%; height:180px; border:1px solid #000; position:absolute; z-index:9999;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="divrelative">
          <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You spoke about "over the parent" in this case, if you accept overlap, simply remove "`overflow-y:auto`" rule.

```css
.parent {
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 100px;
}

.divrelative {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   background: #fff;
   width: 80%;
   height: 180px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="divrelative">
      <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I was not that clear about my question but I have fixed hight. and if the content of parent div increase the scroll has to appear.

Answer (score 0):

change the position to `absolute`

```
.parent{background:#ccc; padding:10px; height:100px;}

.divrelative{position:relative;}

.child{ background:#fff; width:80%; height:180px; border:1px solid #000; position:absolute; z-index:9999;}
```